# How to modify the scheduler of Pegasus WMS

Tags: workflow, scheduling

I'm interested in scientific workflow scheduling. I'm trying to figure out and modify the existing scheduling algorithm inside Pegasus workflow management system from http://pegasus.isi.edu/, but I don't know where it is and how to do so. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pegasus has a notion of site selection during it's mapping phase where it maps the jobs to the various sites defined in the site catalog.   The site selection is explained in the documentation here

https://pegasus.isi.edu/wms/docs/latest/running_workflows.php#mapping_refinement_steps

Internally, there is a site selector interface that you can implement to incorporate your own scheduling algorithms.

You can access the javadoc at

https://pegasus.isi.edu/wms/docs/latest/javadoc/edu/isi/pegasus/planner/selector/SiteSelector.html

There are some implementations included in this package

There is a version of Heft also implemented there. The algorithm is implemented in the the following class.

edu.isi.pegasus.planner.selector.site.heft.Algorithm

Looking at the Heft implementation of site selector will provide you a good template on how to incorporate other site selection algorithms.

However, you need to keep in mind, that Pegasus maps the workflow to various sites and then hands over the workflow to Condor DAGMan for execution. Condor DAGMAn looks at what jobs are ready to run and then releases them to local Condor queue ( managed by Condor Schedd). The jobs are then submitted to the remote sites by Condor Schedd. The actual node on which a job gets executed is determined the by local resource scheduler on the site. For example, if you submit the jobs in a workflow to a site that is running PBS , then PBS decides the actual nodes on which a job runs.

In case of Condor you can associate requirements with your jobs that can help you steer jobs to specific nodes etc.

With a workflow, you can also associate job priorities that determine the priority of the job in the local Condor Queue on the submit host. You can use that to control what job gets submitted by schedd first if there are multiple jobs in the queue.

Comment: Thank you very much. By the way, is there any existing scientific workflow engine that schedule and dispatch workflows into the node without the management of local cluster manager?